# Kommasetzung bei Einschüben

Tags: grammatical-case, comma, scientific-language

Brauche Hilfe bei diesen zwei Sätzen:

"Diese, auf Erfahrung beruhende, Behandlung stellt keine weiteren Probleme dar."

und

"In jedem Fall entscheiden Sie als Arzt, abhängig von dem Zustand und Erkankung des Patienten, über Dosierung Medikaments und weiteren Therapieverlauf."

Sind jetzt beides eingeschobene Nebensätze, aber werden die Kommas hier wirklich gesetzt? oder kann man die weglassen? Und woher weiß ich, wann ein Nebensatz, solcher Art, von Kommas umrahmt wird? Brauche schnelle Hilfe. Vielen lieben Dank schon mal.

Comment: da ist kein Nebensatz. Deswegen ist da auch kein Komma.

Answer (score 4):

Einen Nebensatz kann man daran erkennen, dass er ein finites (gebeugtes) Verb enthält. In beiden Beispielsätzen ist in dem von Komma umgebenen Einschub kein finites Verb enthalten:

> Diese, auf Erfahrung beruhende, Behandlung stellt keine weiteren Probleme dar.

Hier ist kein *auf Erfahrung beruhende* kein Nebensatz, weil kein finites Verb enthalten ist (*beruhend* ist ein [Partizip I](https://easy-deutsch.de/verben/partizip-1/)).<sup>1</sup>

Die Konstruktion mit einem Nebensatz wäre:

> Diese Behandlung, die auf Erfahrung beruht, stellt keine weiteren Probleme dar.

Hier wäre dann *beruht* das finite Verb des Nebensatzes.

Hier muss kein Komma stehen, *auf Erfahrung beruhende* kann einfach als ein Attribut zu *Behandlung* verstanden werden. Ein Komma ist aber möglich. Dann handelt es sich um eine nachträgliche Erläuterung. Die Kommaregeln dafür stehen hier im [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Komma-bei-nachgestellten-Erlauterungen).

---

> In jedem Fall entscheiden Sie als Arzt, abhängig von dem Zustand und Erkankung des Patienten, über Dosierung Medikaments und weiteren Therapieverlauf.

Auch *abhängig von dem Zustand und Erkankung des Patienten* enthält kein finites Verb. Das Komma ist auch hier nicht obligatorisch. Wiederum giilt: Wenn ein Komma gesetzt wird, wird der Einschub als nachträgliche Erläuterung aufgefasst. Der Satz liest sich dann in etwa mit folgendem Sinn

> In jedem Fall entscheiden Sie als Arzt, und zwar abhängig von dem Zustand und Erkankung des Patienten, über Dosierung Medikaments und weiteren Therapieverlauf.

Ebensogut kann man aber auch ohne Komma schreiben:

> In jedem Fall entscheiden Sie als Arzt abhängig von dem Zustand und Erkankung des Patienten über Dosierung Medikaments und weiteren Therapieverlauf.